# I would like to create a set of constants based on the result of a .map

Tags: javascript, json

I am currently iterating over a `.map JSON` result from an `API`, and creating constants for each individual result I'd like to use. I'd like to be able to automate this, as in for when the map detects the "name" `key`, it creates a constant called "index0Name", followed by the value of "name", or the "_text" key and its value.

Is this possible? Example returned `JSON API` info below

```
    {
      "_attributes": {
        "key": "10811142-ce47-44ea-8bdc-5e9f1391f179",
        "number": "5",
        "type": "GT",
        "title": "Title 1- Element Red.gtzip",
        "shortTitle": "Title 1- Element Red.gtzip",
        "state": "Paused",
        "position": "0",
        "duration": "0",
        "loop": "False",
        "selectedIndex": "0"
      },
      "_text": "Title 1- Element Red.gtzip",
      "text": [
        {
          "_attributes": {
            "index": "0",
            "name": "Headline.Text"
          },
          "_text": "HEADLINE"
        },
        {
          "_attributes": {
            "index": "1",
            "name": "Description.Text"
          },
          "_text": "Description"
        }
      ],
      "image": {
        "_attributes": {
          "index": "0",
          "name": "Logo Image.Source"
        },
        "_text": "4b42ada2-8745-4744-8104-fa42c18b3d6b\\IMAGE1.gif"
      }
    }
```

Current code is:

```
const modifiedMap = mapResult[0];
    let inputMap = [];
    if (modifiedMap) {
      inputMap = modifiedMap.map((input, i) => {
        const title = input._attributes.title;
        const state = input._attributes.state;
        const number = input._attributes.number;
        const type = input._attributes.type;

        // React result in here
        }



    return inputMap
    }
```

In the above code, where it manually sets the constant "title" based on what it finds at input._attributes.title, I would like the map to

- Iterate over input._attributes
- Create a constant based on what it finds (Title, state, number...)
- Set the value of that constant based on the value it finds of the corresponding key

Any help is appreciated as always.

Comment: you're using the word "name" and "key' and "value" in a confusing way so I'm not entirely sure what you mean. There's no "name" anything in a json object, you may mean "key". There are only "key: value" pairs. Try to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I apologise. Do you notice how I create the manual constants in the second piece of code?

I like to be able to iterate over input._attributes, and then create a set of constants based on what it finds. In that case, it would find input_attributes.title, and create a constant called 'title' and set its value to be the value it finds during the map.

Is that clearer? Apologies.

Comment: Dynamically determined variables names are problematic. How would you use them, when you don't know beforehand what they are? No, you should stick with the object you received. It already offers those "variables" (or "constants"): they are *properties*. You should use them like that.

Comment: Ah okay, I was hoping this might work, as some results have extra attributes, and some do not. I was hoping to automate finding extras, rather than manually having to account for them maybe being there. Thanks for the help.